# What is the End Of File/Stream keyboard combination to use with System.in.read()

Tags: java, eof, console-input

Apologize if this trivial question has already been answered, I cannot find it at SO.
Reading lines from the IDE console with this Java trivial code (Windows 7 and Eclipse Kepler):

```
int v;
try { while ((v = System.in.read()) != -1) System.out.println(v); }
catch (IOException e) { ; }
```

How the user can make the value v equal to -1?
(I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> and other keys without repeatable behavior, but the loop is interrupted randomly)

Comment: Let say this is an int

Comment: I believe this is console-dependent.

Comment: I use Windows, and running the code in Eclipse, if that helps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Control` + `D` should send the EOF character as excepted , but it is an bug in Eclipse.

One of the user reported as

```
    In Kepler 4.3 eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000 on Linux the problem 
    still exists in the Java console. I found the following workaround:

    If you leave the console to focus on another view, and then refocus on the console,
    then Ctrl-D (EOF) works as expected.
```

Follow [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159803)

---

When using Eclipse in Windows, `Control + Z` sends the EOF character.

Comment: Thanks a lot and bravo! I must use Ctrl-Z (Windows). Changing the view, for instance I select the Problems tab and then Console, allows CTRl-Z recognition... wow.

Comment: 5 years later and this still isn't fixed on the new 2021-03 release, and it makes the run configuration option for automating standard require manually sending an EOF character.

Answer (score 1):

Testing this out using Groovy in a Windows command prompt, ctrl-D doesn't work while ctrl-C does:

```
C:>groovy -e "while(v = System.in.read()){ println v }"
^D
4
13
10
-1
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

First I hit ctrl-D then enter, resulting in output ctrl-D, 4, 13, 10 (the last three being EOT, CR, LF, I guess, not sure what ^D amounts to in this case).
Then I tried ctrl-C and the '-1' end-of-input was sent.
So it seems this is dependent on the shell as Dev says.

Comment: Ctrl-C doesn't work for me, but Ctrl-Z is ok (within Eclipse console). I've the bug mentioned by Mani, and need to change the focused view to have this input taken into account.

Answer (score -1):

Use the **control-D character** (type D while holding down the control key) to indicate to a program reading from the standard input stream that you have finished entering input. The control-D character is often written as **^D**.

Comment: On Mac it's Cmd+D (⌘+D).